# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv2

Tags: python, opencv, pip

When I try cv2 using

```
pip install cv2
```

it shows the error written in the title.

My code is a python code using opencv.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install `opencv`, not `cv2`.

For python2:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

For python3

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3:

```sh
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```